# jrean/laravel-user-verification custom attributes location

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm using the jrean/laravel-user-verification package to do email verification on my users. I'm using Laravel 5.5 and the package is working as it should. However there are some attributes/properties that you can override by entering them into your code. For some reason, I can not get them to work correctly as I do not think I am configuring them in the correct spots.

From the [github.com](https://github.com/jrean/laravel-user-verification) readme, the attribute list is below.

**Attributes/Properties**

To customize the package behaviour and the redirects you can implement and customize six (6) attributes/properties:

```
$redirectIfVerified = '/';
```

Where to reditect if the authenticated user is already verified.

```
$redirectAfterVerification = '/';
```

Where to redirect after a successful verification token verification.

```
$redirectIfVerificationFails = '/email-verification/error';
```

Where to redirect after a failling token verification.

```
$verificationErrorView = 'laravel-user-verification::user-verification';
```

Name of the view returned by the getVerificationError method.

```
$verificationEmailView = 'laravel-user-verification::email'
```

Name of the default e-mail view.

```
$userTable = 'users';
```

Name of the default table used for managing users.

I've tried to put these into different controllers mainly the auth/RegisterController.php controller, the user.php class, and in the config/app.php files. They don't see to take effect. Where would I put these options so I can override the package defaults?

Comment: just follow the instructions in github and use `vendor:publish`. all files will come. views, config, providers, etc

Comment: I've done all of that. It's working just fine. I want to override some attributes as listed above, but not sure where to place these variables.

For example I want to set $redirectAfterVerification = '/dashboard';

Answer (score 1):

The variables should be added to the class where the VerifiesUsers trait is used. In my case, this is the `Auth\RegisterController.php` class. I was testing this before, but the attribute I was using to test wasn't working. It's still not working, however all other attributes are working so I at least have them configured in the correct spot now.